# Thymeleaf - Context-relative and slash ending url

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, url, thymeleaf

```
<a th:href="@{'delete?id='+${user.id}}">X</a>
```

When I access `/admin`: The url become `delete?id=`

But when I access `/admin/`: The url become `admin/delete?id=` (that is the one I want)

So should I use Server-relative URL as an alternative in this case, or should I just assume `/admin/` is a wrong URL and use

```
<a th:href="@{'admin/delete?id='+${user.id}}">X</a>
```

for `/admin`

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I think you should be using context relative urls.  (Also, you shouldn't building urls using string concatenation -- thymeleaf supports variables.) My recommended syntax:

```
<a th:href="@{/admin/delete(id=${user.id})}">X</a>
```